# Problems getting started with android

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I'm new to andoid programming but not new to programming. I have installed and used many ide's and many languages. My usual experience is that I install the ide, create a hello-world project and it compiles and runs. Later on there are usually some more cryptic issue that take a bit of head-scratching.

My goal with android it to write a program that copies the current date to the clipboard and exits.

First I tried kivy with bulldozer. It fails with errors about command line options that aren't documented. The I tried python-for-android. It fails with similar errors that are not explained anywhere.

So I thought to go straight to AS and use c++ or kotlin. I installed it, created an activity project and tried to build. All the while it was complaining about adb server. After 15 min searching I needed to turn off mDNS (why was it on by default?) Then the build failed because it was configured to demand a newer version of gradle than what the setup installed (this makes sense?)

Closed everything an reopened. Got this:
Minimum supported Gradle version is 8.0. Current version is 7.5.1.
Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Change Gradle version in Gradle wrapper to 8.0 and re-import project
Open Gradle wrapper properties
Gradle Settings.

2 hours later, after many more errors and head-scratching, the app finally ran.

So, my question, is this degree of obscurity necessary? Useful?

It's really a shame that after so many have put so much effort into these projects, that none of the saw fit to finish the job and actually make the usable (or even work. I just got a reply on Discord that said "ignore the p4a docs, use this link instead. You see what I mean. I don't know if that link will help but I searched the web for several hours and never discovered it.

everything I could think of